# Use of QtWebEngine possible in Windows store?

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

I'd like to recompile our Qt project with the Windows RT/UWP environment in order to be able to deploy to the Windows store.
We rely heavily on QtWebengine.
Is QtWebEngine allowed in that context ?
(For IOS I know we must find a workaround to use UIWebView/WKWebView instead)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, not a programming question

Comment: i found the answer In the Qt documentation:"On Windows, Qt WebEngine only supports Windows Vista or newer as target platform. Due to use of newer API in Chromium, Windows XP is not supported. WinRT is not supported, either." win rt is AFAIK a synonym for UWP apps, but as the terminology changes each half year there remains uncertainty...,

Comment: @MrEricSir windows store apps require a subset of the whole Windows API jungle , so I think it's a programming related question.